# Create object DOM twitter boostrap modal without overwrite

Tags: javascript, object, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create different object for not overwrite the code, in my modal window.

I have the following window modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="box-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><!-- Aqui va el titulo de la pagina modal -->@yield('modal_title')</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         @yield('modal_body')
                        <div class="alert hidden" id="modal-alert"></div>
                        <!--Aqui va el cuerpo de la página modal -->


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- Aquí va el pie de la pagina modal -->
                    @yield('modal_footer')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

With the Dom. I get the title, the body, the footer of the modal

```
 var modalBox = $("#box-modal"),
        modalBoxObject = modalBox[0],
        modaltitle = modalBoxObject.getElementsByClassName('modal-title')[0],
        modalContent = modalBoxObject.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0],
        modalFooter = modalBoxObject.getElementsByClassName('modal-footer')[0];
```

I want to create different objects of the modal and give it different content.

Example:
If I press event create user, I put a title the modal-title

If I have other event show user. I have edited the title but without overwrite the create user's title;

Example

```
$("#create").on('click', function(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       modaltitle.innerHTML = "Create user";

   });
   $("#modify").on('click', function(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       //this overwrite my DOM. I want to have differents modal windows with differents title example.
       modaltitle.innerHTML = "Modify";

   });
```

Any example?. I've that create one class. Or I have that create other window modal for "showuser" and different other for "create user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you should refer to the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) and do like this :

1. Use button as trigger with a custom [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) :

   ```
   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#box-modal" 
        class="btn btn-primary" data-action="view">View</button>
   ```
2. Create a event handler and retrieve the related button which opened the modal :

   ```
   $('#box-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
       var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
       console.log(event);
       var action = button.data('action');

       var modal_title = $(this).find('.modal-title');
       var modal_body = $(this).find('.modal-body');
       var modal_footer = $(this).find('.modal-footer');

       switch(action) {
           //Test each case
       }
   })
   ```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/86/)